# why create a new row when gorm update associations

Tags: go, go-gorm

I followed the document code same struct and migrate

here's my model

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    AddressID uint           ``
    Address   UserAddress    `gorm:"references:ID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL"`
}
```

```
type UserAddress struct {
    gorm.Model
    Address   string         `gorm:"type:varchar(50);notNull"`
}
```

document works fine when migrate and create data

```
    db.AutoMigrate(&UserAddress{})

    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
```

but when I try update data use associations

```
    user := &User{
        ID:        1,
        AddressID: 1,
        Address: UserAddress{
            Address: "new address",
        },
    }

    db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&user)
```

document says:

> If you want to update associations’s data, you should use the FullSaveAssociations mode:

then it still create a new data of address and update user.address_id

```
INSERT INTO `user_address` (`address`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`) VALUES ('changed','2021-08-13 14:07:39.149','2021-08-13 14:07:39.149',NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `address`=VALUES(`address`),`created_at`=VALUES(`created_at`),`updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`),`deleted_at`=VALUES(`deleted_at`)
```

where am I missing here or it just doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give a unique id for Address. So it create new address record with autoincrement ID. And update the ID value associated with it.

```
user := &User{
        ID:        1,
        AddressID: 1,
        Address: UserAddress{
            ID: 1,
            Address: "new address",
        },
    }
```

Comment: I think. Set it in Address. The purpose of this AddressID is to specify the relationship between the User and Address. Not create UserAddress with ID 1.

Comment: I've verified it. In your current model definition, You need to specify UserAddress.ID. Then no new rows will be created.

Comment: I tried add UserAddress.ID and update (must with Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true})), it works. almost misunderstand gorm :3, thanks so much,